# extracting only texture filenames being used in maya file from the list of filename paths

Tags: python, maya

I have got the following code for listing the texture files being used in my Maya file. When I run the code I get a list of texture files with their paths. But I just need a list of filenames and I'm trying to extract them but not getting the list as I expect.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Gets all 'file' nodes in maya
fileList = cmds.ls(type='file')

texture_filename_list = []

# For each file node..
for f in fileList:
    # Get the name of the image attached to it
    texture_filename = cmds.getAttr(f + '.fileTextureName')
    texture_filename_list.append(texture_filename)

print texture_filename_list

The output is  [u'D:/IRASProject/RVK/SAFAA/Shared/sourceimages/chars/amir/4k/safaa_amir_clean_body_dif.jpg', u'D:/IRASProject/RVK/SAFAA/Shared/sourceimages/chars/amir/4k/safaa_amir_body_nrlMap.tif', etc]
```

Now from this list I need to extract the filenames only so I add the code as,

```
for path in texture_filename_list :
    path.split('/')
    path_list.append(path)    
print path_list
```

When I execute then I get the same list for path_list. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use os.path.basename(), something like this:

```
import os
import os.path

new_list = []

for each in texture_filename_list:
    file_name = os.path.basename(each)
    new_list.append(file_name)
```

This will give you something like:

```
['safaa_amir_clean_body_dif.jpg', 'safaa_amir_body_nrlMap.tif']
```

If you want it without the extension you can change it like this:

```
import os
import os.path

new_list = []

for each in texture_filename_list:
    file_name = os.path.basename(each)
    stripped_file_name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
    new_list.append(stripped_file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks I got the filenames. But I still get the list as [u'safaa_amir_clean_body_dif.jpg', u'safaa_amir_body_nrlMap.tif']. How do I get rid of the 'u' at the beginning?

Comment: It's ok. I don't have to bother getting rid of it as it doensn't make any difference. Thanks

Comment: It just means that the string items are unicode as opposed to ascii, it does'nt actually affect the list, try printing each item of the list and see what happens. If you really want to get rid of it I *think* you could use str(file_name / stripped_file_name) on the append line, might not work though.

Comment: BTW, don't use 'path' as a variable name since it's a common module.