# how can search an outside file structure from inside of Maya using python

Tags: python, textures, maya, autodesk, pymel

I am an experienced Maya user but fairly new to programming and there is something I am trying to figure out.
I am attempting to create a function for use inside of Maya that would allow me to search the file structure for a texture file.

What I want it to do is this:

```
if texture_name is missing:
    access folder containing this scene
    go up one file to character folder
    if textures folder exists:
        if object matching texture_name exists:
            set this folder as new texture path
```

alternatively it could do something like this:

```
texture path is A:B/C/D/texture_name
    if A:B/C/D/texture_name == False:
        if A:B/C/E/texture_name == False:
            if A:B/F/E/texture_name == False:
```

etc.
replacing the texture path one layer at a time until it works

EDIT:
I have found a workaround that generates the texture paths I need, but I am still looking for a way to Query whether a certain file exists. Like the objExists function but to check for files outside the maya scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the os module to check if it exists.
There is os.path, os.path.isfile()

[extracting only texture filenames being used in maya file from the list of filename paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089647/extracting-only-texture-filenames-being-used-in-maya-file-from-the-list-of-filen)